# Rename mp3 file names to a pattern

Tags: sed, awk, basename

I have a list of like names likes so:

```
/A/B/C/D/E/F/filename_album1-003.mp3
```

its more like album\d+

I would like to change it to something like

```
/A/B/C/D/E/F/filename_song-3.mp3
```

`song` is just a fixed string.

I tried something like `basename -s '.mp3'` and then `sed -e /_album//g` but this misses the number ` and doesn't remove all the leading 001. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the `perl` version of `rename`? If you do, you could simply use: `rename 's/album1-0*/song-/' < list-of-names.txt`

Comment: I do not have that rename, is there a more portable way with sed and awk?

Comment: You can download it from CPAN, see my POST =)

Comment: Full `rename` command is less than 40 non empty lines -- we can almost copy by hand! And it also works in pipes: `find | rename 's/_album1-0*(\d+).mp3$/-song-$1.mp3'`  (untested)

Comment: If you have `rename` from `util-linux` you could run `rename album1 song *.mp3` and then run `rename song-0 song- *.mp3` twice (assuming range is `001-999`).

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
$ zmv -n '(**/)(*_)*-0#(<->.mp3)' '$1$2song-$3'
mv -- A/B/foo_bar-0002.mp3 A/B/foo_song-2.mp3
```

remove `-n` if satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
rename -n 's/_album1-0*/-song-/' /A/B/C/D/E/F/filename_album1-003.mp3
```

(remove `-n` switch if your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're getting the new "song" name from, your starting with `filename_album1-003.mp3` and switching to `filename_song-3.mp3`...

If you're getting the song name from the ID3 tag, then using a program that can rename mp3's from the tag info would be easier. One like easytag, mp3rename, lltag... there are several in the Debian repos & others